# Heat Transfer in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: thermodynamics, boundary-conditions

Lets say one has an infinitely long cylinder with some boundary heat terms on $r=r_0$ of the form $T(r=r_0, \phi,z)=T_0(\phi,z)$. What is the general solution for this type of equation? The general solution is of the form;

$T(r,\phi,z) = \sum_m J_m(kr)(A_me^{im\phi}+B_me^{-im\phi})(C_me^{kz}+D_me^{-kz})$

However how does one implement a boundary condition that is $z$ dependent, since in order to find the coefficients one needs to find a function orthogonal to $e^{kz}$, for real valued $k$.